# Customize Bootstrap on a Yeoman project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yeoman

I have an Angular application scaffolded with Yeoman and using Twitter Bootstrap.
On their website, Bootstrap purpose to customize the design of their components (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). Then you download a zip containing Bootstrap files with your customization.
On the downloaded zip there are:

```
bootstrap/
  fonts/
  js/
  css/
  config.js
```

I just modified the variables, so I suppose that the only interesting thing for me is the config.js (I already have the Bootstrap's files).

So my question is where I have to put this file, or what do I have to do to use my Bootstrap customization?

Hope I'm understandable :)
Thanks !

Comment: swap your current bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css with the ones from the downloaded bootstrap/css folder. As far as I know js and fonts stay the same.

Comment: my bad, If you toggle some js options on customize page, you will have to swap bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js files as well.

Comment: The config.js file defines the variables that have been customized. What do you do with this file ?

Comment: you just save it, so the next time you can use it for further customization if needed. "Have an existing configuration? Upload your config.json to import it." on the http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple.
I put the CSS files instead of mines in my Yeoman project at `bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css` (4 files) and the JS files in `bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js` (2 files).

Thanks [*@yuyokk*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30908503/4927984) for your comment on the config.js file, which may be useful for further customization.